# CuckooCritical Error + Error in HTTPSConnection after checking for Update

Tags: cuckoo

I have followed the installation guide in cuckoo , and reach to the configuration part, without any altering and after altering the server and Ip address to my private IP address, Am still having the same problem :

```
****Checking for updates...

Error checking for the latest Cuckoo version: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='cuckoosandbox.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /updates.json?version=2.0.7 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fabe819ba50>, 'Connection to cuckoosandbox.org timed out. (connect timeout=6)'))!

2024-02-15 14:00:12,809 [cuckoo] CRITICAL: CuckooCriticalError: Unable to bind ResultServer on 192.168.56.1:2042 [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address. This usually happens when you start Cuckoo without bringing up the virtual interface associated with the ResultServer IP address. Please refer to https://cuckoo.sh/docs/faq/#troubles-problem for more information.
```

What I have tried:

1. Change nameserver in `/etc/resov.cof` from 127.0.0.53 to my private IP address
2. Change them also in these files: `conf/routhing.cong` & `virtualbox.cof`
3. I tried to add vboxnet0 to HOST only network from my VB setting /network (Adapter 2), Adapter 1 is NAT
4. I tried to change the connected WI-FI
5. I tried to Ping Cuckoo.org but it is not working

I tried many ways but still no luck - can anyone help?

Also, can this problem be related to the update (under development)?